# Spring MVC Rest API not working when implementing InitializingBean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have a basic API setup with Spring MVC Rest as following.

```
public abstract class AbstractApi implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    protected ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;

    /* ... */

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(validatorFactory);
    }
}


@Controller
@RequestMapping("books")
public class BookApi extends AbstractApi {

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BookApi(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Book> getBooks() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookRepository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The server returns `404 - Not Found` if I send `GET /books` request with above configuration.

But, if I make `AbstractApi` un-implement `InitializingBean`, it works fine. Also, annotating `@PostConstruct` to `afterPropertiesSet()` instead of implementing `InitializingBean` works.

Why is Spring `@Controller` API not working when implementing `InitializingBean`?

Comment: Please post the related stacktrace.

Comment: @Bnrdo No stacktrace. Looks like the mapping for the request is not configured.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. I tested in on my own and everything works as expected. What I'm suggesting is to remove `@Autowired ValidatorFactory` in `AbstractApi` class just for testing purpose. Implementing `InitializingBean` is not related to the request mapping handler mapping. My working code is:

```
public abstract class AbstractApi implements InitializingBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("after properties set");
    }
}
```

and my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("books")
public class BooksController extends AbstractApi {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getBooks() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and starting log from tomcat:

```
2016-01-28 16:48:03.141  INFO 2238 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-01-28 16:48:03.317  INFO 2238 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-01-28 16:48:03.329  INFO 2238 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
2016-01-28 16:48:03.405  INFO 2238 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-01-28 16:48:03.405  INFO 2238 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1815 ms
2016-01-28 16:48:03.512  INFO 2238 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-01-28 16:48:03.515  INFO 2238 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
after properties set
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. That makes sense but what I am confused with is how implementing `InitializingBean` making the request mapping not working.

Answer (score -1):

Your current @RequestMapping("books") path is incorrectly specified. When running locally on port 8080 looks like http://localhost:8080books

and should be @RequestMapping("/books") -  http://localhost:8080/books

give that a try.